# Impossible click+drag a CollectionView in Assistant editor

Tags: uicollectionview

I have a single view application then I added a tab bar controller.

On one on of the two new view, I drag a collection view and a collection view cell.

In fact, I follow this Youtube tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pvvn1L2aPyA
, and I don't succeed to click+drag the collection View in a header file (2'20).

When I open Assistant editor with my collection view selected, the automatic file diaplyed is UIViewController.h. I don't think it's the good file and I can't click+drag the Collection View.

I tried to create a new subclass of CollectionView or ViewController linked with this View but nothing works. (I created an Objective-C file "PageCollectionView" subclass of UICollectionView. I changed the custom class of my Collection to "PageCollectionView and nothing change).

Can anyone help me to create a file where I can click+drag my Collection View and then try to follow this Youtube tutorial ?

Thanks

Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I had to create a new View controller (File->New->File->Objective-C Class-> Name as you want (ex:DanViewController) and subclass of UIViewController).
And then in storyboard, select the Identity inspector (in Utilities) and set the custom class to the name of your newly-created class (ex:DanViewController).
By choosing this file now in your assistant editor, I can click+drag every controller of my View.

Hope it will help

Pierre